# Does python smtpd support TLS?

Tags: python, smtpd

I'm trying to make a simple email server, but I'm finding that python's smtpd library doesn't support TLS, and I can't find any examples of servers implementing TLS.

Is this implemented in any third party libraries, or extension to the stdlib?  I found some examples for python2, but I'm looking for python3 not that python2 is deprecated.

Comment: The documentation says that `smtpd` is deprecated and you should use [`aiosmtpd`](https://aiosmtpd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: See [Enabling STARTTLS](https://aiosmtpd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aiosmtpd/docs/smtp.html#enabling-starttls)

Comment: thanks!  huge help